# Shouldn’t “chose” be “choose” in “Is this the moment you chose to tell me this”?

Tags: word-choice, tense, sequence-of-tenses

I told a friend something.

They said, "**Is** this the moment you **chose** to tell me this?"

I opined that it should be, "**Is** this the moment you **choose** to tell me this?"

Or maybe, "**Was** that the moment you **chose** to tell me this?"

Which one do you think is correct, or more suited? I feel that since the particular moment when I her told that thing had passed, it can't be referred to as "this moment" any more. If it can be, "Is this moment you choose to tell me this?" sounds like the correct thing to say.

Answer (score 2):

Both "chose" and "choose" are grammatical and natural, but they have slightly different meanings.

> Is this the moment you **chose** to tell me this?

suggests you chose the moment before you told me, like it was planned before.

> Is this the moment you **choose** to tell me this?

suggests you chose the moment as you were speaking.

It's correct to use "is" and "chose" together because the moment is the present, but the choice is in the past. It would also be correct and natural to use "***Was** this the moment...*" because the moment was chosen in the past, and "this" still makes it clear that the moment is the present one.

Answer (score 0):

Either “choose” or “chose” is grammatical, but in the context described, “choose” might be more common, at least in U.S. speech.

Logically, the present is an immediately vanishing instant lying between past and future. So if your friend is responding  to something you said three seconds ago, the past tense, “chose,” is logically correct, but people do not always use language according to strict logic. The present tense is often used to describe events that immediately preceded the current instant and are related to what is of interest at the current instant. I personally would use “choose” in these circumstances because I would feel that the conversation on this topic is happening now rather than in the past.

The same thought supports “this” over “that.” This is now, and that was then.

In English usage, the present tense can relate to a brief, emotionally or socially determined **interval** rather than an imperceptible physical **instant**.